# Drupal: Calendar navigator, placement

Tags: drupal

[image]

It's the red marked "navigator" I am talking about. I need to move them away so they don't mess up my design. I have tried to change a lot of different settings without no success.

Here is the View for it:

[image]

What should I do?
I am using the following themes: Pixture Reloaded 7.x-2.2 and AT Core 7.x-2.2

Modules: Calendar, chaos tools, views, date modules..

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious some mix up in css. It is a large possibility that elements created by calender inherit some css properties.

Easy fix is to view the source code of he page. Using FireBug(for firefox) or some alternative will make it easier to find. You will find some css rules being applied to your menu. Just try to enable and disable some css rules and see what happens.

When you find mischief just write a css function with higher priority which would negate that other global rule.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and i solved just yesterday hacking some css. I share you here what i have done in my case that i think i will help you also or at least work around there.

**First** to fixing the big buttons of the calendar navigation you should look in your theme css files at some css class called "ul.pager li a" or "ul.pager li span" there must be a property like "display:block" that is causing this buttons see that way. i just commented that property and they look as normal them should be.

In my case the theme css file was "navigation.css" and this property inside that file is found at line 375. Maybe in yours could be similar, anyway you can check and find where is using the firebug extension for firefox inspecting that buttons.

**Second** for fix the position of this navigation buttons is something similar but in the css file of the calendar module itself, after modifying the core css file of the module i recommend you to override it placing a copy of it in your template css folder and declaring it on the .info file of the template. In my case the file was calendar_multiday.css, in the line 778 and 818 there are the classes ".view .date-nav-wrapper .date-prev" and ".view .date-nav-wrapper .date-next" inside them with the property "right" and "left" i controlled the positions where must be this buttons.

This is the work around on how i solved it, hope this works for you also but if not anyway the problem is close there.